# switch case statement in AS3 not working properly with XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, switch-statement

I'm making a switch case statement that iterates through the season tag in my XML file, which works fine considering my one trace statement prints out 1 of the 4 seasons. But the case always defaults. But I don't understand why. This switch case stmnt is within a for loop.

```
switch(seasonOn.season){
                case "spring":
                    springList.push(seasonOn.place);
                    break;
                case "summer":
                    summerList.push(seasonOn.place);
                    break;
                case "autumn":
                    autumnList.push(seasonOn.place);
                    break;
                case "winter":
                    winterList.push(seasonOn.place);
                    break;
                default:
                    trace("none of the above");
            }/*trace(seasonOn.season);
            trace(winterList.length);*/
```

Comment: See my answer. I suspect it's because you're doing a direct comparison between a string literal and an XMLNode. Cast the XMLNode to a string first then compare your literals against it. The code in my answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine...

```
var seasonData:String = "<data><season>spring</season></data>"

var seasonOn = new XML(seasonData);

var currentSeason:String = seasonOn.season;

var springList:Array = [];
var summerList:Array = [];
var autumnList:Array = [];
var winterList:Array = [];

switch(currentSeason){
case "spring":
    springList.push(seasonOn.place);
    trace("spring");
break;

case "summer":
summerList.push(seasonOn.place);
    trace("summer");
break;

case "autumn":
    autumnList.push(seasonOn.place);
    trace("autumn");
break;

case "winter":
    winterList.push(seasonOn.place);
    trace("winter");
break;

default:
    trace("none of the above");
}
```